# Что за mock объекты? (java)

Tags: java, mvc, юнит-тесты, тестирование

Изучаю паттерн MVC, в моих задач очень часто встречается такая фраза как mock-объекты, такое объяснение нашел в гугле - *"Объект Mock используется для модульного тестирования. Если у вас есть объект, методы которого вы хотите протестировать, и эти методы зависят от какого-либо другого объекта,вы создаете макет зависимости, а не фактический экземпляр этой зависимости. Это позволяет вам изолировать свой объект."* и куча подобных ему. Все это понятно на каком-то интуитивном уровне. Может кто-нибудь разъяснить, что и как более простым языком, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mock-объект — это объект "заглушка". Например, необходимо протестировать функцию, которая посылает запросы по сети:

```
package main;

sub sendRequest {
    my $request = shift;

    my $ua = Mock::UserAgent->new;

    my $response = $ua->request( $request );

    if ( $response->is_successful ) {
        # что-то делаем ...
    } else {
        # падаем в случае ошибки
        die $response->status_line;
    }

    return $response;
}
```

В данном случае mock-объектом является $ua, которая была создана с помощью специального модуля Mock::UserAgent (пример). И её задача заключается лишь в имитации действий. Например её метод `request` никаких фактических запросов по сети не посылает, а делает вид, что типа он послал и вернул ответ. Это нужно, например, для блочных тестов, когда, к примеру, доступа к интернету нет, да и это и не требуется для тестирования. Такой mock-метод `request`, мог бы выглядеть так:

```
package Mock::UserAgent;

sub request {
    my $request = shift;

    my $response = HTTP::FakeResponse->new;

    return $response;
}
```

Это одно из применений mock-объектов. Другое, так же связанное с тестированием, заключается в том, чтобы в своей функции использовать модуль, которыё ещё не разработан, но необходим для функционирования вашей функции, но разрабатывается другими разработчиками, например, или вы используется методику "разработка через тестирование". И вот, чтобы их не ждать, вы можете создать mock-объект, который типа возвращает нужные вам данные, как если бы это был реальный объект, что позволит вам разделаться с тестами для вашей готовой функции и перейти к разработке следующей. Т.е. это своего рода "изоляция зависимостей" при тестировании.

Не каждый же день имеется возможность тренироваться с партнёром-боксёром, чтобы отработать прямой удар, а отрабатывать его надо, поэтому используют mock-объект — груша.

Comment: Забыл указать язык программирования, этот мне непонятен, я изучаю MVC на Java. Но 3 абзац все прояснил, спасибо:)